# Get values from the string with length of no greatwer than 2 character

Tags: regex, string, linq

I have the following expression

```
List<string> Images = Regex.Matches(html, @"(?<=/PI/).*(?=/500/)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

It is getting all value between `/PI/` and `/500/`

I want to make sure that that each value is no longer than 3 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=/PI/).{0,3}(?=/500/)
```